# How to make the LuaLaTex logfile more readable, or filter it?

Tags: luatex, latexmk, debugging, logging

I use Latexmk to compile lualatex to PDF.
The resulting `.log` file is very hard to read.
I already added the silent switches to the `.latexmk` configuration file

```perl
# make it less verbose 
$bibtex_silent_switch=1;
$biber_silent_switch=1;
$dvipdf_silent_switch=1;
$dvips_silent_switch=1;
$latex_silent_switch=1;
$lualatex_silent_switch=1;
$makeindex_silent_switch=1;
$pdflatex_silent_switch=1;
$xelatex_silent_switch=1;
```

But the `.log` file is still filled with redundant and useless messages.

Is there a wrapper script, which greps the more interesting items?

Example for less interesting lines during debugging:

```
Package: scrlfile 2017/04/13 v3.23 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
Package scrlfile, 2017/04/13 v3.23 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
                  Copyright (C) Markus Kohm
```

or

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex
Package: expl3 2017/07/19 L3 programming layer (code)
\ucharcat@table=\catcodetable5
\c_max_int=\count89
\l_tmpa_int=\count90
\l_tmpb_int=\count91 
(many more lines follow...)
```

Comment: lines like `(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex` are actually one of the more useful bits (and the most common reason we ask people to post log files here) a common source of error is to have old versions of packages in the input path, and seeing the full path to the used file is easiest way to check that.  The lines `\l_tmpa_int=\count90` are almost entirely useless, if I ruled the world, latex wouldn't output them at all:-)

Comment: Can you show us a typical and minimal example luaTeX file producing too much log-output and explain what are those parts you deem the more interesting ones ?

Comment: You could try [ltx2any](https://github.com/reitzig/ltx2any) as build tool. It produces nice markdown or PDF log output.